# XCode 4 and Titanium: TARGET_BUILD_DIR is incorrectly set

Tags: xcode, titanium, appcelerator

Hi there
i am just starting with Appcelerator Titanium an run into this problem

**The Situation**
I changed the SYMROOT/TARGET_BUILD_DIR in XCode 3 to a global directory. Today i installed XCode4 (and didn't even changed any default property).

**The Problem**
I just want to buld the KitchenSink Demo using Titanium 1.2.2. If i build/launch for iOS I get this message

> [ERROR] Your TARGET_BUILD_DIR is incorrectly set. Most likely you have configured in Xcode a customized build location. Titanium does not currently support this configuration.
>   [ERROR] Expected dir /Users/fabian/Development/Workspaces/2011/titanium/appcelerator-KitchenSink-c17b77f/build/iphone/build/Debug-iphonesimulator, was: /Users/fabian/Development/Workspaces/iphone_experiments/xcode_build/Debug-iphonesimulator

XCode4 is still using the old global TARGET_BUILD_DIR. How do I change/delete this?

Answer (score 1):

I think this was the solution:

Delete the TARGET_BUILD_DIR property in username/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist and restart XCode 4

Comment: This has not worked for me unfortunately as TARGET_BUILD_DIR is not even in the plist file.  Specific error I am getting is one to do with the case of the users folder for some reason: [ERROR] Your TARGET_BUILD_DIR is incorrectly set. Most likely you have configured in Xcode a customized build location. Titanium does not currently support this configuration.
[ERROR] Expected dir /Users/matthew/Projects/Titanium Studio Workspace/helloworld/build/iphone/build/Debug-iphoneos, was: /users/matthew/Projects/Titanium Studio Workspace/helloworld/build/iphone/build/Debug-iphoneos

Comment: i Managed to solve the same probleme by deleting "SYMROOT" under IDEApplicationwideBuildSettings inside username/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist . No need to restart Xcode. Thanks for pointing to the right file anyway !